# add_rewrite_rule ignored even with regex set to .*

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

Every guide seems to be simple and straight-forward---just place a small block of code into functions.php and then flush the rewrite rules by going to permalinks and saving. But my function refuses to be acknowledged even with the most lenient descriptors possible.

I have slowly whittled down the code I'm using from this:

```
function new_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^u/(.+)/?$','index.php?pagename=user-profile&user=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'new_rewrite');
```

to this completely catch-all version that proved to me something is seriously wrong here:

```
function new_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('.*','index.php','top');
}
add_action('init', 'new_rewrite');
```

When I use the above code---which as far as makes sense to me should take anything given to it and return the homepage---instead it is completely ignored and everything works the exact same way as before I tried to write any rules.

And let me reiterate: I have placed this in functions.php where I've added plenty of other functions such as add_custom_query_var to great success and I have also been flushing the rewrite rules constantly.

What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: You should see the generated rule in the htaccess if it has been correctly flushed.

Comment: @vard Ok I didn't know that it wrote to the htaccess. I checked and the rule is not appearing there. What could possibly be blocking my flush?

Comment: Maybe some permissions issue on the htaccess file?

Comment: @vard I checked and it's 644 where only the "owner" can write. But that should be fine, right?

Comment: @vard one thing I just thought of is that my htaccess is in the root but my wordpress installation is in a subfolder. Hmmm.

Comment: Well Wordpress should write in the htaccess that is on the same level as _wp-config.php_. Do you see the rule in that htaccess? You should see "BEGIN WORPRESS" and "END WORDPRESS" comments in that file - Wordpress use them to add the generated rules.

Comment: The htaccess that is in the root has the begin and end Wordpress stuff, but that is because I originally had my install there. There is no htaccess in /main where my installation and wp-config are, so I am assuming that is the problem. I'll mark you as the answer if you formulate your comments into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress use the htaccess located at the root of his installation - not the root of the website server folder - so the htaccess that WP will override is the one that is as the same level as *wp-config.php*.

By default the WP htaccess contains those two comments:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
```

Wordpress use them to know where he should add the rules generated by `add_rewrite_rule` - it is sometimes usefull to move this comments to make rules more higher or lower compared to some other custom rules.